# Reply to messages using message ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been looking at the Gmail App documentation and I cannot find a solution for this.

I have a list of messageID's on a spreadsheet, and I would like to reply to those messages specifically using an Apps Script function. Is this something that would be possible?

Edit: here is a wroking sample script using the suggestion below:

```
const messageID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A1").getValue();
const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageID);

Logger.log(message);

message.reply("This is a test message");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the message ID from the message header you can try the following script:

```js
function replyToMessageId() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID of the Spreadsheet");
  const messageID = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Name of the sheet").getRange("A1").getValue();
  const body = "This is a test message";
  var message = GmailApp.search("Rfc822msgid:"+messageID);
  message[0].reply(body);
}
```

What you need to do in this case is to obtain the message by doing a search using the Gmail search operators, in this case `Rfc822msgid`, and the message ID that you have.

In this sample code I am just replying to one person, however if your message includes multiple recipients you may want to use `replyAll()` instead of `reply()`.

#### References:

- [Gmail Search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)
- [replyAll(body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replyallbody)
- [reply(body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replybody)

Comment: Since a sample sheet was not provided I did not know the format of your current data with the list of message IDs, therefore in my example I am just getting a message ID I have in cell A1 from a testing sheet, but you could change that part to retrieve the IDs from  the range you are working with. I can also help you modify the script if you provide me with a sample sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've edited my post to include your sample text, but I'm receiving the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reply')". When I try to log out the  variable "message", I am just receiving an empty array: Info   [ ]

Comment: Ok I made some edits and was able to get it to work! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, the documentation was very helpful.